# How to get Android SDK for Unitech PA760?

Tags: android, jar, sdk, barcode-scanner, aar

I can get HTML based scanner demo for Unitech models.

https://portal.unitech.eu/Products/Default.aspx?RFID=1&PG=67

I need to get SDK files (.aar or .jar file) to integrate into Android Application.

Comment: Have you tried contacting them? StackOverflow is not the place for asking where to find something in the internet.

Comment: @JamesZ Yes raised my questions to support team.